# Tokenize a c string

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the string thet's after /xxx/, there is a must be forward slashes, two of them, then the string that I need to extract. 
Here is my code, but I don't know where to set the null terminator, there is a math problem here

```
char str[100] = "/709/usr/datapoint/nviTemp1";
char *tmp;
char token[100];

tmp = strchr(str+1, '/');
size_t len = (size_t)(tmp-str)+1;
strncpy(token, str+len, strlen(str+len));
strcat(token,"\0");
```

I want to extract whatever after `/709/` which is `usr/datapoint/nviTemp1`

Note that /709/ is variable and it could be any size but for sure there will be two forward slashes.

Comment: `strcat(token,"\0");` will do virtually nothing. You should do `token[strlen(str+len)]='\0';` instead. Or You may use `strncpy(token, str+len, sizeof(token));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple improvement:

```
char str[100] = "/709/usr/datapoint/nviTemp1";
char *tmp;
char token[100];

tmp = strchr(str+1, '/');
if (tmp != NULL) strncpy(token, tmp + 1, sizeof(token)); else token[0] = '\0';
```

`tmp` points the slash after `"/709"`, so what you want is right after there.
You don't have to calculate the length manually.

Moreover, `strncpy` copies at most (third argument) characters, so it should be the length of the destination buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that the string starts with `"/NNN/", then it is simple:

```
char str[100] = "/709/usr/datapoint/nviTemp1";
char token[100];
strcpy(token, str+5);  // str+5 is the first char after the second slash.
```

If you need to get everything after the second slash:

```
char str[100] = "/709/usr/datapoint/nviTemp1";
char token[100];
char* slash;
slash = strchr(str, '/');     // Expect that slash == str
slash = strchr(slash+1, '/'); // slash is second slash.
strcpy(token, slash+1);      // slash+1 is the string after the second slash.
```

Comment: no, its not sure it starts with /NNN/, sometime the path is /NNNNN/

Comment: I think you should make sure that `slash` isn't `NULL` for safety.

Comment: @MikeCAT: Safety is the OPs responsibility.  I'm trying to provide a *clear* and *simple* answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)-

```
sscanf(str,"%*[/0-9]%s",token);  
 /* '/709/' is read and discarded and remaining string is stored in token */
```

`token` will contain string `"usr/datapoint/nviTemp1"` .

[Working example](https://ideone.com/x7U3y2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter and a basic while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) return 0;

    char *s = argv[1];
    char slash = '/';
    int slash_count = 0;

    while (slash_count < 2 && *s)
        if (*s++ == slash) slash_count++;

    printf("String: %s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the `s` pointer, like duplicating it with `strdup` or using `strcat`, `strcpy`, etc...

Outputs:

```
$ ./draft /709/usr/datapoint/nviTemp1
String: usr/datapoint/nviTemp1
$ ./draft /70905/usr/datapoint/nviTemp1
String: usr/datapoint/nviTemp1
```